# How to allow an application running in a Windows Sandbox to connect to my 'host' webapp / db / etc?

Tags: windows-sandbox

I have a Windows Sandbox running on my Windows 11 notebook. In it, I wish to connect out of it and back to my windows 11 'host' ... which is running a number of docker instances for things like web apps, databases, etc.

For example:

My notebook 'localhost' is running:

- mssql
- postgres

I have these two databases running on my notebook. great.

I then start Windows Sandbox. The app starts up -> a fresh version of the Sandbox. I then download some DB app like Azure Data Studio and wish to connect to these two database -> but they are "outside" of my Sandbox.

How can this be done please?